# When an iOS app directly enters the background state?

Tags: ios, multitasking

Can someone tell me a scenario when an iOS application directly enters the background state?.

Here I have quoted the lines from iOS Application Programming Document in multitasking section.

> If your app is launched into the background instead—usually to handle
>   some type of background event—the launch cycle changes slightly to the
>   one shown in Figure 3-3. The main difference is that instead of your
>   app being made active, it enters the background state to handle the
>   event and then is suspended shortly afterward.

***Added ...***

In the iOS Application Programming Document if you see the figure 3.3 titled *Launching an app into the background*, the flow is like this **User taps app icon -> main() -> UIApplicationMain() -> Enter background**. Is there any chance when the app directly enters background when an user taps app icon. I interpreted the image like this. Is it correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One scenario for a background launch (App X)

- X registered for location background mode in its Info.plist
- X is run by the user, and registers for significant location changes while running
- The user switches to another app Y, so X goes to background and is then suspended (it will be returned to background mode whenever there is a significant location change to handle, and then be suspended again)
- The app Y eats lots of memory, so suspended applications (including X) get kicked out of memory
- a significant location change comes in. Now X is launched into background.

Answer (score 1):

### Scenario

Lets say you had registered your application for Local/Push notification. Then your application will launch in background run some code which have written inside your `applicationDidEnterBackgroud:` delegate method and then it terminates immediately.

#### Check listing 2

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

**EDIT:**

> Applications might also find local notifications useful when they run
> in the background and some message, data, or other item arrives that
> might be of interest to the user. In this case, they should present
> the notification immediately using the UIApplication method
> **presentLocalNotificationNow: (iOS gives an application a limited time
> to run in the background).** Listing 2-2 illustrates how you might do
> this.

Comment: Listing 2 is demonstrating how to execute some code after entering the background. The OP is asking how can an app enter directly into the background in the first place.

Comment: @MartinH, OP has specifically mentioned that,"Tell me, In what scenario". I have mentioned the scenario in my answer and in addition I have shown OP that which method will get called in order to handle the background execution.

Comment: Hi Owl I edited my question with another question. Can you please clarify me?. Thanks

Comment: Could you please post a link as well.

Comment: Hi here is the link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Comment: Incoming local/remote push notifications do not launch your app in the background. If the user ignores the push notifications, you app is not launched at all; if the user "opens" the push notification (clicks on the alert, taps it in notification center, ...) your app is launched in the foreground.

Comment: @TammoFreese, Check my edit : Have you thoroughly read the documentation? OP asked for just a scenario without any conditional triggering description. If you have the push notification on then 100% app will open in background and handle the associated code inside the application delegate.

Comment: Yes, I have. The question was how an app directly *enters* the background state (and from the doc snippet it gets clear that it is about launching into the background state). A push notification can be received by an app that *is* in the background, but a push notification will not make an app *enter* the background state.